# Form inputs are not passed within repeatable forms

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am trying to pass variable value from visualforce page to my custom controller. But it is constantly null.
This is my page:

```
<apex:page id="productCatalog" controller="ItemController">
    <table class="table" id="block">
       <apex:repeat value="{! items[key]}" var="item">
           <tr>
              <td class="col-md-2"></td><apex:outputText value="{! item.Name}"/>
              <td class="col-md-2">
                 <apex:form >
                     <apex:pageblock >
                         <apex:inputText value="{!myinput}"/>
                         <apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="outputID" action="{!MyMethode}"/>
                     </apex:pageblock>
                 </apex:form>
              </td>
           </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public with sharing class ItemController {
 public string myInput{get;set;}

    public void MyMethode(){
        System.debug(myInput);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why the `<apex:form >`  is inside the loop?

Comment: @SarojBera  I have no idea how to pass parameter entered in certain row to controller by the clicking the certain button:
|<input field>| |<button>|
|<input field>| |<button>|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<apex:form> <apex:inputText value="{!myinput}"/>` in `<apex:repeat>` tag.

At the time of submit, controller does not know which instance of 'myinput' and from which Form you are referring to. My suggestion is to take the 'myinput' variable out of repeat tag. You can check with below code the value is coming perfect fine -

```
<apex:page id="productCatalog" controller="ItemController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:repeat value="{!items}" var="item">
            <table class="table" id="block">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2"></td><apex:outputText value="{! item.Name}"/>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </apex:repeat>

        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:inputText value="{!myinput}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="outputID" action="{!MyMethode}"/>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you really want to use <apex:form > <apex:inputText value="{!myinput}"/>
in <apex:repeat> tag. We can write something like below using apexFunction, HTML input, JS

```
<apex:page id="productCatalog" controller="ItemController">
    <table class="table" id="block">
       <apex:repeat value="{!items[key]}" var="item">
           <tr>
              <td class="col-md-2"></td><apex:outputText value="{! item.Name}"/>
              <td class="col-md-2">
                 <apex:form >
                     <apex:pageblock >
                         <apex:inputText value="{!myinput}"/>
                         <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="MyMethodeApexFunction(this.previousElementSibling.value);"/>
                     </apex:pageblock>
                 </apex:form>
              </td>
           </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="MyMethodeApexFunction" action="{!MyMethode}" reRender="outputID">
            <apex:param name="tempparamater" value="" assignTo="{!myinput}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to place buttons and inputs within each row of table. But I don't know how to say to my controller that this is exactly This input.

Comment: @sviatlana check the updated answer.

Comment: @Sviatlana Welcome!! :)